# Enable Password and Confirm Password fields in Registration form

Tags: users

i want to have registration form in my drupal site, but that is limited to the fields email and username.

I also want to have fields "Password" and "Confirm Password" in the registration form, so that the user does not need to check his email for his password and can login to the site directly after registration.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module can do everything you need.

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal login system in an external module by offering the following features and usability improvements:
>
> 1. Allow users to login using either their username OR their e-mail
>      address.
> 2. Allow users to login immediately.
>      Provide a login form on Access Denied pages for non-logged-in (anonymous) users.
> 3. The module provides two login block options: One uses JavaScript to display the form within the block immediately upon clicking "log in". The other brings the user to a separate page, but returns the user to their original page upon login.
> 4. Customize the registration form with two e-mail fields to ensure accuracy.
> 5. Optionally redirect the user to a specific page when using the 'immediate login' feature.
> 6. Optionally redirect the user to a specific page upon validation of their e-mail address.
> 7. Optionally display a user message indicating a successful login.
> 8. Optionally combine both the login and registration form on one page.
> 9. Optionally have unvalidated users purged from the system at a pre-defined interval (please read the CAVEATS section of INSTALL.txt for important information on configuring this feature!).
> 10. Integrates with Rules module to do various tasks when a user validates via email validation process (see http://drupal.org/node/880904 for an example)

Comment: Any idea for Drupal 8 as this module isn't available yet?

Answer (score 8):

I got it: I needed to de-select the checkbox that allows to enable the email confirmation of the users, which is listed under "User settings."

In Drupal 7, in admin panel, under Configuration > People > Account Settings > Registration and cancellation > deselect the checkbox: Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account.

Comment: But isn't it possible to ask for passwords, and get e-mail confirmation? Just to check if the e-mail excists...

Answer (score 1):

[User registration password](http://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module does exactly what you want.

> Let users register with a password on the registration form when verification mail is required.
>
> By default, users can create accounts directly on the registration form, set their password and be immediately logged in, or they can create their account, wait for a verification e-mail, and then create their password. With this module, users are able to create their account along with their password and simply activate their account when receiving the verification email.

Comment: I second that.

User Registrationpassword unblocks a user After users click the confirmation link in the e-mail they got after submitting the registration form.